# リストの中を区切りたい

Tags: python

```
x ＝ []
a=abc
b=3

x.append(a,b)

print(x)
```

結果

```
[(abc,3),(def.4)....]
```

このようにa.bの数値が変わっていく中で結果のように続けて（）の中に収納するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

わかりにくくてすみませんが、教えていただきたいです。

追記です
date:

> a
>   12345
>   1234
>
> b
>   123456
>   1234
>
> c
>   1234567
>   1234

---

このようなdateの場合に
">"を認識したら x=[] にaを
12345の行を読み込んだら、続けて x=[] をいれ、
x=[(a,9),(b,10),(c,11).....]と続けたいです
この場合、空行を認識したらdefを発動したらいいのかとおもうのですが、
思うように行きません。
もしアドバイスしていただければお願いいたします。

Comment: 別の質問は追記ではなく、別の質問として新しく作成するようお願いします。

Answer (score 5):

結果の部分に記載された内容を元に、本質問の目的を **リストの中に、変数`a` と `b` の組（タプル、tupleとも言います）を格納していきたい** であるものとして回答します。

その場合、以下のような方法で実現可能です。

```
def append_tuple(x, a, b):
    t = (a, b)    # tuple
    x.append(t)
    # 上記は x.append((a, b)) と書くことも可能です


def main():
    x = []
    append_tuple(x, "abc", 3)
    append_tuple(x, "def", 4)

    print(x)    # => [('abc', 3), ('def', 4)]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: note: 質問者の方のレベル感から、分かりやすさの為にあえて関数として切り出しています。

Comment: ありがとうございました。
解決いたしました。

Comment: 解決した場合、回答ではなく「解決としてマーク」というボタンを利用してください。